# Missing grant type despite proper headers

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, kotlin, spring-security-oauth2

Hey everyone I am having some trouble with Spring Boot and OAuth. I keep getting "Missing grant type" with curl and in Postman. I have set `Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded`. I have also set the grant types in my authorization server. I am at a loss as what could be the issue. Here is my authorization server.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
class AuthServerConfig(@Value("\${test.oauth.tokenTimeout:3600}")
                   var expiration: Int): AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter() {

@Autowired lateinit var userDetailsService: UserDetailsService
@Autowired lateinit var authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager

@Bean fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
    return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
}

override fun configure(configurer: AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer) {
    configurer.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
    configurer.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
    configurer.tokenStore(InMemoryTokenStore())
    configurer.allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST)
}

override fun configure(security: AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer) {
    security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
}

override fun configure(clients: ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer) {
    clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient("test") // TODO: Set to settings in application.yml
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
            .secret(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(expiration)
            .scopes("read", "write")
}
```

}

It also seems that in `TokenEndpoint.java` my parameters are always empty and the `tokenRequest` object's grant type property is null.

Edit:
Here are pictures of my postman and git bash using curl
[image]

[image]

Comment: Show your HTTP request with headers and the URL with query parameters.

Comment: Don't use '-d', you have to send query parameters.

Comment: @dur omg im an idiot! thanks so much!